# Compare Metadata between orgs

Tags: metadata

I need to compare metadata between different environments/orgs in salesforce.Are there any tools like kdiff3(compares the code) that will help in comparing the metadata?

Answer (score 1):

There are some in appexchange, depending on your requirements you can choose.
For instance Metadata Glimpser https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5HSYEA3. Or you can use salesforce CLI (https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/forcecli) export metadata to local directories and compare using  kdiff3.

Answer (score 0):

The Salesforce Toolkit (http://sftoolkit.co/) has an Org Compare tool and a Schema Lister.